# Change in Wordpress Title

Tags: wordpress, edit, title

May be it is a unreal question. But i want to know that is there any way to change automatically "-" to "," in wordpress post title?

i.e. :
if someone add a new post with this title = `wordpress-example-title`
it automatically converts it into = `wordpress,example,title`.

I did a thing, i put `$title=str_replace('-',',',$title);` in `wp-includes/post-template.php`. Now post heading is working well, it is converting hyphens into commas, but the title of the post is still same. I'm using yoast wordpress seo which is force rewriting titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should NEVER change the core WordPress files. You should only have to change your theme files for this (usually the functions.php file). There is a filter that you need to use to change the title called `wp_title`. You can call it using `add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_title' );` but since your using YOAST, you need to add priority to it so its executed after YOAST like so `add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_title', 11 );`

Here is an example:

```
function theme_title( $title ) {
    return str_replace('-',',',$title);
}

// This is called after YOAST
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_title', 11 );
```

Comment: Yes, i know i shouldn't edit wp files, but i was not finding any other solution, that's why i did that but now i've removed removed that code.
i tried to add this code into function.php but its not working. Showing same hyphen thing. I dont know php, so please elaborate more.

Comment: It is working for browser title when i disable yoast. But i want to use yoast too, and want to change post heading too. Where should i add that add_filter code. I added that in functions.php.

Comment: done, i just change wp_title into wpseo_title (this is yoast generated title) and added a new filter for the_title too.. Thanks sir, for help :D